# Is there a better way to check the type of a child node and returning accordingly?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I am working on the development of a small language using ANTLR. I have an interpreter class ready, which is able to recognise and execute any syntax tree of this language. Unfortunately, ANTLR produces parse trees. Thus, I am using the visitor pattern to convert a parse tree to a syntax tree.

Given the following rule,

`<Factor> = <Identifier> | <Literal>`

the `visitFactor(FactorContext ctx)` within my visitor class, should return a literal or identifier....

```java
 public Statement visitFactor(FactorContext ctx) {
        if (ctx.ID() != null)
            return new Identifier(ctx.ID().getText());
        else if (ctx.literal() != null)
            return visit(ctx.literal());
        return null; // should never happen, factor *must* be either id or literal.
    }
```

My question is the following. Is there a better way to know the type of Factor's child? Or do I have to work with if-statements, checking whether each child is non-null?

Comment: Depending on your language, it should be possible to structure your grammar in such a way that a separate AST is not necessary. Note that ANTLR4 supports direct left-recursion and precedence (based on the order of alternatives), so it's often possible to define a single `expression` rule without splitting it into levels of precedence like `Term`, `Factor` etc.

Comment: For example if your rule for expressions currently looks like [this](https://git.io/JfnxP) or [this](https://git.io/Jfnxo), you could rewrite it like [this](https://git.io/JfnxV) and the tree for `1+2*x+y` will then look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMA1N.png) (the alternative labels don't show up in the GUI, but each expression in the tree will in fact be an instance of a specific subclass as defined by the labels). So that might make it a lot more reasonable to use the parse tree as an AST.

Comment: thanks, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [alternative labels](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels) like this:

```
factor
 : ID      #factorID
 | literal #factorLiteral
 ;
```

which will then produce the following methods instead of the single `visitFactor(...)`:

```java
public Statement visitFactorID(FactorIDContext ctx) {
   return new Identifier(ctx.ID().getText());
}

public Statement visitFactorLiteral(FactorLiteralContext ctx) {
   return visit(ctx.literal());
}
```